# How to bind all Jenkins settings & job to Docker image

Tags: image, docker, jenkins

I downloaded the oficial Jenkins image. After that, I created a volume `docker volume create jenkins-data`. Create container `docker container run -d -p 8080:8080 -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home --name jenkins-local test/my_repo:jenkins_commit_1`. Made some settings changes and created my job. Then made commit and push to docker hub. 
If I stop container, remove it, and run again - it works fine on my local machine(all settings and jobs are saved), but on the other one(if I download my image from docker hub) -- my image has default state, without any plugins, settings, jobs. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you please confirm whether the image which has been pulled is the same which you have pushed, which commands you are using?

Comment: 1) `docker ps` --> CONTAINER ID = e05935e9b043 2) `docker commit e05935e9b043 test/my_repo:jenkins_commit_1` 3) `docker push test/my_repo:jenkins_commit_1`

Comment: so for docker pull you have to use:- docker pull test/my_repo:jenkins_commit_1
can you please confirm if your are using same coomad?

Comment: Yes, from docker hub I codied next command: `docker pull test/my_repo:jenkins_commit_1`

Comment: It is impossible to send any settings with image, which were saved in volume. It's a normal case for docker.